# how could I launch Trino in AWS EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, presto, trino

When I create the EMR cluster, in the 'Application' step I have chosen 'Trino'. I can confirm this.

When I connect to the Master Node using SSH, and type 'presto --version' they give me 'presto:command not found'.

Also tried 'presto-cli' as [EMR docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-considerations.html) said, still got 'presto-cli' not found.

Also,as [Trino Docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html), I should go to the 'bin/launcher' directory and launch trino. However, I do not know where is this in my Cluster.

I am a noob. Could you please tell me how to run/launch trino in AWS EMR?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to startup the Trino CLI, you should use 'trino-cli'. (Recall that PrestoSQL was renamed to Trino a couple of years ago which triggered a whole host of renaming both inside and out.)